# JMS Wildfly implementation

Tags: java, jboss, jms, wildfly

I'm writing an application that runs as a daemon and makes `restful` request periodically, I'm trying to implement a system where I have another application (preprocessor) that will be sent the `JSON` responses from the daemon.

My plan is to use `JMS` for this, my understanding is that I can send the `restful`  responses I receive in my `daemon.jar` to a `Queue` using a JMS provider, I've been looking into using JBoss.

So my understanding now is that I need to run a `JBoss` 7 Application server, or a `Wildfly AS`, I plan to run this server on a raspberry pi 2 for testing purposes, Have I got this right?

Regarding the client and receiver, Do they both need to be running on the server? I'm confused by this, can I have the `Wildfly AS` running on the pi, have the `sender` running on another machine and the `receiver` running on a 3rd machine?

Do my `sender` and `receiver` need anything specific on them to communicate with the AS other than  maybe some libs for `Wildfly`?, I've seen `Hornetq` mentioned a few times, but am unsure how this fits into the process.

Comment: Have a look at [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/); I think you don't need the whole container stuff for just using a queue

Comment: This application may expand and I may need more of Wildflys features in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working, I couldn't find a start to finish example of setting this all up, but managed to piece it all together from different examples.

the Sender(`Producer`) and Receiver(`Consumer`) don't need to be running on the server, I have all 3 running on different machines, they have to know the address of the `Wildfly AS` and the name of the queue(`HornetQ`) they are connecting to.